# Trigger on temp table

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have the below trigger creating temp table that work fine, but needs trigger to fire on the Minor and Serious as well.

At this stage I only have one substring that fires on word Significant but need to trigger on Minor and Serious.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_DNSeverity]
ON [dbo].[Messages]
AFTER INSERT
AS  
  Declare @msg nvarchar(4000),@part nvarchar(4000),@sever nvarchar(100);  
  DECLARE @Idx int,@Idx2 int ,@i int,@msid int;
  SET NoCOUNT ON;

  SELECT * INTO #Temp
    FROM inserted

  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #Temp)
  BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @msid = MessageID,@msg = Content FROM #Temp



    SET @Idx    = CharIndex('Incident impact :',@msg);
    SET @Idx2   = CharIndex('Customer                     : Something',@msg);

    if ((@Idx2>@Idx) AND (@Idx2-@Idx<100))
    BEGIN
        SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11);
        SET @i     = @Idx;


            IF      (@sever= 'Serious')
                SET @sever = 'Severity 1'
            --Else IF (@sever = 'Minor')
            Else IF (@sever = 'Minor')
                SET @sever = 'Severity 3'
            Else IF (@sever= 'Significant')
                SET @sever='Severity 2';      
            SET @part  = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx2,4000);
            SET @msg   = SUBSTRING(@msg,1,@Idx -1) + 'Incident impact :'+ '' + @Sever +'&#xD;&#xA;'+ @part;

        UPDATE Messages  SET Content= @msg WHERE MessageID = @msid; 

    END
    DELETE FROM #Temp WHERE MessageID = @msid;        
  END     
  DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

To elaborate, what I have done on emails was creating a table called Messages and each time a message is received to the Table called Messages a trigger would change Significant to Severity 2 which is working fine. Now I need to get it to look for the words Minor and Serious and change it to its correct Severities as indicated at `BEGIN`

```
    SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11);
    SET @i     = @Idx;
        IF      (@sever= 'Serious')
            SET @sever = 'Severity 1'
        Else IF (@sever = 'Minor')
            SET @sever = 'Severity 3'
        Else IF (@sever= 'Significant')
            SET @sever='Severity 2';
```

What I need the trigger to do is to fire on Minor and Serious when it's detected, at this stage it only fire on Significant and set it to Severity 2.

The above is the original code as I have it currently and I know my code is not working on the Serious and Minor as I have test it. Now I'm stuck and cannot get it to trigger on wording Minor and Serious.

Please note that I fell into this scenario which I have not mentioned and me knowing anything bout coding is zults, I had to google hard till where I am now with the trigger and getting past this it a mountain to move...so I can only get the one to word to trigger on `SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11);`
which is `IF (@sever= 'Significant') SET @sever='Severity 2`, all I need now is just some guidance in the correct direction and that's it.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear in many ways. First, it's not clear whether the code you posted is the old code that you have to modify or the new code already modified. It is not clear what you expect the trigger to do. It is also unclear why you're processing rows one at a time instead of processing all the rows in bulk. Can you please clarify these points?

Comment: The trigger fires for each row inserted, regardless of the contents fo the row. What do you mean with "fire"? I'm sorry, but you need to understand that we are not seeing what you are doing and we have absolutely no knowledge of your business cases, except for the information you shared here. If you need helpful answers, you need to be very specific.

Comment: Have you attempted to step this through debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, 
`SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11)` 
is always getting 11 characters of data and putting that in @sever.

'**Significant**' IS 11 characters,so that always works.  If there are any characters after 'Serious' or 'Minor', your SUBSTRING is including them as well and your comparison won't match.

In your example:

```
if ((@Idx2>@Idx) AND (@Idx2-@Idx<100))
    BEGIN
        SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11);
        SET @i     = @Idx;
```

You could add an extra command to account for this:

```
if ((@Idx2>@Idx) AND (@Idx2-@Idx<100))
    BEGIN
        SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@msg,@Idx+18,11);
        SET @sever = SUBSTRING(@sever,1,CharIndex(' ',@sever))
        SET @i     = @Idx;
```

Another alternative is to use `LIKE` instead of **'='**

```
IF (@sever LIKE 'Serious%')
    SET @sever = 'Severity 1'
ELSE IF (@sever LIKE 'Minor%')
    SET @sever = 'Severity 3'
ELSE IF (@sever LIKE 'Significant%')
    SET @sever = 'Severity 2';
```

Comment: @ Scott Hodgin you are truly the main man thanks for the suggestion and the correct direction...adding LIKE OPERATORS did the trick, thank you very much and lots appreciated

Comment: If you think I have answered your question, please 'accept' it so others will know you're not still looking for a solution